# for loop is not working within my script

Tags: bash, for-loop, bioinformatics, blast

I made a script in bash that run blastx.

```
#!/bin/sh -l 
# $Id: Barrine.sh federicogaiti $

echo "Right now it is:"
date
echo ""
function usage() {
echo "Barrine.sh script by Federico Gaiti, March 2013."
echo ""
echo "Run Blastx"
echo ""
echo "Usage: "
echo "Barrine.sh <All contigs (fasta extension)> <Number of fasta split sequences> <Head file with PBS command where you set up account, walltime, etc..> "
echo ""
echo "Example: "
echo "Barrine.sh InputFasta n Head "
echo ""
exit 1
}

# Testing if the number of arguments is correct
if [ $# != 3 ]
then
    usage
        exit
    fi

### Declaring variables
InputFasta=$1    MY ORIGINAL FASTA FILE WITH ALL THE SEQUENCES
n=$2                 NUMBER OF FILES I WANT MY FASTA FILE SPLIT
Head=$3           PBS OPTIONS
n4=$((n/4))
n41=$((n/4 + 1))
n2=$((n/2))
n21=$((n/2 + 1))
n43=$((n/4 * 3))
n431=$((n/4*3 + 1))


echo Loading Modules
module load ucsc_utilities/20130122
wait


echo Split input FASTA in n FASTA file
faSplit sequence ${InputFasta} ${n} ${InputFasta}_Split_S 
wait



echo blastx command splitting it in 4 jobs to make it faster
    for i in {000..0$n4} ; do echo "blastx -query ${InputFasta}_Split_S$i.fa -evalue 0.0001 -max_target_seqs 100 -db nr -num_threads 8 -outfmt '7 qseqid qlen sseqid pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send ppos evalue bitscore score' -out ${InputFasta}_blastx$i.csv" ; done > ${InputFasta}_Job1.sh


    for i in {0$n41..$n2} ; do echo "blastx -query ${InputFasta}_Split_S$i.fa -evalue 0.0001 -max_target_seqs 100 -db nr -num_threads 8 -outfmt '7 qseqid qlen sseqid pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send ppos evalue bitscore score' -out ${InputFasta}_blastx$i.csv" ; done > ${InputFasta}_Job2.sh


    for i in {$n21..$n43} ; do echo "blastx -query ${InputFasta}_Split_S$i.fa -evalue 0.0001 -max_target_seqs 100 -db nr -num_threads 8 -outfmt '7 qseqid qlen sseqid pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send ppos evalue bitscore score' -out ${InputFasta}_blastx$i.csv" ; done > ${InputFasta}_Job3.sh


    for i in {$n431..$n} ; do echo "blastx -query ${InputFasta}_Split_S$i.fa -evalue 0.0001 -max_target_seqs 100 -db nr -num_threads 8 -outfmt '7 qseqid qlen sseqid pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send ppos evalue bitscore score' -out ${InputFasta}_blastx$i.csv" ; done > ${InputFasta}_Job4.sh

wait


echo Head the PBS commands to the Job files 
    for i in {1..4} 
        do 
        cat ${Head} ${InputFasta}_Job$i.sh | sed "s/BlastJob/BlastJob_$i/g" > ${InputFasta}_BlastJob$i.sh 
        done
```

I will then submit the 4 Jobs to barrine server.
What I am supposed to obtain is 4 jobs containing this:

```
    blastx -query TEST_Split_S000.fa -evalue 0.0001 -max_target_seqs 100 -db nr -num_threads 8 -outfmt '7 qseqid qlen sseqid pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send ppos evalue bitscore score' -out TEST_blastx000.csv
blastx -query TEST_Split_S001.fa -evalue 0.0001 -max_target_seqs 100 -db nr -num_threads 8 -outfmt '7 qseqid qlen sseqid pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send ppos evalue bitscore score' -out TEST_blastx001.csv
blastx -query TEST_Split_S002.fa -evalue 0.0001 -max_target_seqs 100 -db nr -num_threads 8 -outfmt '7 qseqid qlen sseqid pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send ppos evalue bitscore score' -out TEST_blastx002.csv
blastx -query TEST_Split_S003.fa -evalue 0.0001 -max_target_seqs 100 -db nr -num_threads 8 -outfmt '7 qseqid qlen sseqid pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send ppos evalue bitscore score' -out TEST_blastx003.csv
blastx -query TEST_Split_S004.fa -evalue 0.0001 -max_target_seqs 100 -db nr -num_threads 8 -outfmt '7 qseqid qlen sseqid pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send ppos evalue bitscore score' -out TEST_blastx004.csv
blastx -query TEST_Split_S005.fa -evalue 0.0001 -max_target_seqs 100 -db nr -num_threads 8 -outfmt '7 qseqid qlen sseqid pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send ppos evalue bitscore score' -out TEST_blastx005.csv
blastx -query TEST_Split_S006.fa -evalue 0.0001 -max_target_seqs 100 -db nr -num_threads 8 -outfmt '7 qseqid qlen sseqid pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send ppos evalue bitscore score' -out TEST_blastx006.csv
blastx -query TEST_Split_S007.fa -evalue 0.0001 -max_target_seqs 100 -db nr -num_threads 8 -outfmt '7 qseqid qlen sseqid pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send ppos evalue bitscore score' -out TEST_blastx007.csv
............
blastx -query TEST_Split_S050.fa -evalue 0.0001 -max_target_seqs 100 -db nr -num_threads 8 -outfmt '7 qseqid qlen sseqid pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send ppos evalue bitscore score' -out TEST_blastx050.csv
```

But what I got in my script is just:

```
blastx -query TEST_Split_S{000..050}.fa -evalue 0.0001 -max_target_seqs 100 -db nr -num_threads 8 -outfmt '7 qseqid qlen sseqid pident length mismatch gapopen qstart qend sstart send ppos evalue bitscore score' -out TEST_blastx{000..050}.csv
```

Someone can help me in solving the problem?
If I use the for loop outside my script works fine.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Brace expansion* happens early.

*Parameter expansion* happens later, so you can't use variables or other parameters in a way that controls brace expansion.

From [the bash(1) man page:](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion, tilde expansion,
>   parameter, variable and arithmetic expansion and  command 
>   substitution  (done  in  a left-to-right fashion), word splitting, and
>   pathname expansion.

This will prevent statements like `for i in {000..0$n4} ; do` from working as intended.

Also, be sure to remember the `-v` and `-x` arguments to display the actual commands executed.

Comment: The cure is probably `for i in $(eval echo {000..0$n4}); ...`; the pre-eval replaces `0$n4` with the appropriate value (50?), and then the `eval` re-does the brace expansion on `{000..050}` giving you the separate values. Beware: `eval` is dangerous in general.  However, this is an entirely benign use of it if the variables such as `$n4` are guaranteed to contain numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Jonathan. I will surely try to use eval. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation DigitalRoss. All isworking fine now and I put -x command for debugging.